# How to restrict apache Guacamole access to certain IP addresses?

Tags: security, web-server, web

How to restrict apache Guacamole access to certain IP addresses?

We want to allow access to ONLY to our office Ip address. Not able to find anything on this topic in the config files.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know does Apache Guacamole not have such a feature by itself.

You would need to place your Guacamole behind a proxy (see [here](https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/1.4.0/gug/reverse-proxy.html)) or a firewall.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option with Apache Guacamole, But I have installed csf firewall and restricted using the following in /etc/csf/csf.allow file.

```
tcp:in:d=8080:s=my-office-ip-01
tcp:in:d=8080:s=my-office-ip-02
tcp:in:d=8080:s=my-office-ip-03
```